# Serial Device Names in MinGW

Tags: gdb, mingw, gnu

I am attempting to use GDB to debug a remote target over a serial line on a windows box using MinGW.   The [`target remote`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Connecting.html) command GDB expects a path to a device driver (e.g. /dev/ttyS0) in order to connect to the remote target.  There are 4 properly functioning serial ports on my machine, but they don't seem to be visible from MinGW.  Is there a way to install them, or is this just not possible in the self proclaimed minimalist MinGW?

I did some searching on [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), Google, and here and wasn't able to find anything relevant.

Comment: Have you tried something like *com1* or *//./COM1* ?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala setting the target to `com1` works perfectly.  Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Just normal serial port naming on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @J.J Hakala com ports are just named `com1`, `com2`, etc in windows.  They are in the root directory so `./com1` works as well.  There is no need to install drivers.

Comment: I'm getting `COM15: No such file or directory.` when I do `target remote COM15`. (COM15 is the serial port name as appears in **Device Manager**)

Comment: @Alaa M. I am really not an expert in this area.  I would suggest opening an new question or contacting J.J. Hakala

Comment: After some investigation I found that Windows is troublesome with `COM[num] , num>9`. Also, when changing the `COM` name in **Device Manager**, some ports are marked as **used**, but actually they are not, and sometimes only choosing one of those "used" ports works. Another thing, Windows (unlike Linux) prints this misleading message also when the port is accessed by another service like [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or [Hype! Terminal](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hypeterminal/)